# Bouncing sound off a wall

Tags: waves, acoustics, reflection, frequency, doppler-effect

Let's say I am moving at a velocity $v$ away from a wall, and emitting a sound toward a wall. Is it true that I hear the sound at the same frequency that I emit it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  In the wall frame, your sound is shifted down in frequency.  It reflects at the frequency that strikes the wall.  As you are receding from the wall, it is shifted down again.  Two doppler shifts in total.

Comment: or one doppler shift, but from twice the relative velocity.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson Specifically one Doppler shift squared, i.e. $(1 - v / c)^2$?